# SSIS access is denied exception when executing package from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS (2014) script task I have a very simple piece of code which checks if there is a file in a shared folder:

`DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["folderSourcePath"].Value.ToString());
Dts.Variables["fileCount"].Value = d.GetFiles().GetLength(0);`

Now:

- When I run the package from Visual Studio - the result is OK
- When I run the package from job on SSIS server - the result is OK
- When I run the package manually from SSMS (right click to package and excecute) I'm getting Access to the path '\server\folder' is denied exception.

All the time the username is the same and the user has full access to the shared folder. I'm logging the System::UserName variable and all the time the user is the same.

So why the package is behaving differently when I run it from hand? How can I get the real username which is used to execute the code and access the shared folder?

Comment: When I try to run from hand package which writes to database, I'm getting Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error. Can it be the same thing for shared folder access? If yes, why it is not using the credentials of the user who runs the package?

Comment: I'd suggest checking sql server configuration manager. See what account is running the sql server service. If it's a service account which does not have access to this shared directory, I suspect that is the problem.

Comment: The service account has access to the shared folder, I will have to check on destination side what username it is trying to use...